# We break a stick at a uniformly chosen random location. Find the probability that the shorter piece is less than $\frac{1}{5}$-th of the original.

Tags: probability-theory

The question is the following:

> We break a stick at a uniformly chosen random location. Find the probability that the shorter piece is less than $\dfrac15$-th of the original.

---

My attempt: $$P\left(X < \dfrac15\right) = 1 - P\left(X \ge \dfrac15\right) = 1 - \left(1 - \dfrac15\right) = \dfrac15$$
So my answer is that the probability is $\dfrac15$.

However, I checked my answer to see if I was right, and I instead found that the answer is $\dfrac25$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You correctly calculated the probability that the _bottom_ piece is smaller than one-fifth, but not the probability that the _shortest_ piece is smaller than one-fifth. The shortest piece could be the top or the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places the second cut can be made such that the smaller one is less than 1/5 the larger one. This explains why the answer is twice what you came up with.